# How to top-up my PayPal account balance above my bank account's daily limit?

Tags: paypal, online-payment

I need to pay 3000 € at IKEA's e-shop*, but my bank account including its credit and debit cards allows only 1000 € per day at maximum user config for the account**. As the only payment option offered, which is not using bank cards is a PayPal account – and this method allows me to gradually accumulate funds and send them at once as expected.

The only way for gradually adding the funds to PayPal account I can think of is to ask a friend with another PayPal account for help and do the following:

1. On day 1, send 1000 € to a friend from my PayPal to his PayPal. My bank account will be charged by PayPal for 1000 €.
2. On day 2, repeat. My account will be charged for another 1000 €.
3. On day 3, repeat. My account will be charged for another 1000 €.
4. After receiving all the funds, my friend will send 3000 € from his PayPal to my PayPal account.
5. Now I have sufficient balance to pay in the e-shop using PayPal.

**Is this probably the easiest way of adding funds to the account***?**  Or did I overlook anything? Do I understand correctly it will be  without PayPal fees?

---

*) I am mentioning this directly because this company does not offer a possibility of bank account transfer, which usually comes with awaiting for all the money to arrive. And this company is too large to set exceptions for individuals. If a bank transfer option was available, I would simply send 1000 € on 3 sequential days and then the order would be automatically considered paid.

**) I can control daily limits, but 1000 € is the maximum amount. I can go to the bank to raise the allowable maximum to any amount, but I do not need that. This is the first transaction I ever met which cannot be resolved by other means.

***) PayPal's [preferred top-up service via Trustly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7HGU.png) is currently out-of-order for my country and moreover, that service is unusable since it violates terms of the bank account, which forbid sharing of login credentials with any parties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently **no way** from my country (Slovakia).

When I consulted the steps suggested in the question with PayPal support, they said they can be evaluated as non-standard behavior (an attempt to circumvent standard free use) and they can be made subject of fees.

When I added a bank account for direct debit, then added direct debit allowance to the account, then verified the account, and then set it up as *preferred payment method*, payment operation in the e-shop opened PayPal and only credit card option was shown for the payment – without any explanation why other payment methods are hidden.

I decided to bear shipping fees and I split the purchase into four batches, each smaller than 1500 € limit and therefore I paid for shipping four times.

Obviously, PayPal has differences between countries which do not allow certain operations in certain countries. In my country, the account currently cannot be topped up and it cannot use bank account with direct debit withdrawal even if it is successfully added to the user profile.

Answer (score 4):

You can add money to your own paypal account, you don't need to involve a friend.

Just login into your paypal account, there is a button where you can [transfer money](https://www.paypal.com/us/cshelp/article/how-do-i-add-money-to-my-paypal-balance-from-my-bank-help114) from your bank account (or other sources). If there is a limit below 3.000€, you can just repeat it until you have the full amount.

Also, have you tried just paying the full amount with paypal? They will just get it from your (verified) bank account afterwards. (There is a limit of 2.500€ for unverified bank accounts, but, well, just verify it).

Also, the limit on your bank account probably only applies to money you want to transfer out yourself (and/or pay with your card), not for withdrawals done by other companies from your account. If I understood you correctly, IKEA offers the option to make a withdrawal from their side, so that might probably just work. (IKEA offers different payment options per country, so I cannot check which payment options they offer to you).

Last but not least, I would also check if you cannot just *temporarily* increase your limit in your online banking, there usually is a setting, or some way to contact the bank about it (as you are not the only one that uses a daily limit for safety reasons, but also want to transfer more than that occasionally). Maybe just check what happens if you try to transfer more than 1.000€, they might point you to that setting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It happens to bump into my previous research and testing. Your 2nd paragraph refers to the button, but the button only runs Trustly service – please see my third footnote.  Your 3rd paragraph collides with my second footnote which says about any daily limit and it cannot be raised. So if PayPal induces a withdrawal from the account, it is counted to its daily limit 1000€. This also applies to the rest of the answer. All ways of money transfers from my account count towards daily limit and I am unable to temporarily set it above 1000€. Hence my question on this site.

Comment: Additional note: Normally, limit of 1000€ is not a problem, it never was since these limits were introduced many years ago. Companies either accept gradual sending of funds or I can go to my bank and after personal identification, I can sign any transfer statement, even for 100k €. So I am happy with my small online limits which cannot be raised online above 1000€, since they are able to mitigate the damage from most types of common threats.

Comment: Is Trustly the *only* way you can top-up? You say that it you pay (send 1000€ to your friend) via Paypal, they charge your bank account. And you say they cannot do exactly the same if you want to top-up (e.g. send money to yourself)? Why would Paypal depend solely on Trustly, a direct competitor of Paypal, to make business with you? Paypal charging the bank account should be the default way to do it. I would recheck your assumption that it doesn't work (and/or add your country if it is something very country specific).

Comment: About the daily online limit: Have you actually checked if it applies to direct debits? It would be really unusual if it does (while the online limit is very usual). You have no control over when they arrive (so you might not be able to pay for food in the supermarket just because your landlord/insurance/tax office charged your account today). Also, while it makes sense to limit transfers authorized by you as a security feature, the security feature with direct debits is that you can just contest them. (Assuming from "€" that SEPA(-like) regulations apply in your country too).

Comment: You are correct with the direct debit option. I have linked two of my bank accounts to PayPal: one via credit card (currently set as 'preferred') and another one via direct debit. Switching the preference to the latter one will lead to use of direct debit and that will work. And yes, Trustly is the only offered option, just check the hyperlink to a screen clip I added to the question. Maybe this is different for your country/region. Your profile does not indicate it so I am just guessing, without possibility to check specific one.

Comment: I tested the stuff further and found there is no current way from my country. I upvoted your answer because it might be useful for use in other countries, and I also added my own answer concluding my research.